Azure Pipeline stage being skipped due to previous stages when condition allows for it
I am trying to allow the skipping of intermediate stages while still allowing an initial and final stage to run. For example, in this picture:

I want the deploy-dev to be run when tests & scans are skipped manually in the Pipeline Run > Stages options.

I have the following Azure Pipeline stages:
  - stage: prebuild
    displayName: 'Pre-pipeline'
    jobs:
      - job: A

  - stage: build
    displayName: 'Build'
    dependsOn: prebuild
    jobs:
      - job: B

  - stage: scans
    displayName: 'Scans'
    dependsOn:
      - build
    jobs:
      - job: C

  - stage: tests
    displayName: 'Tests'
    dependsOn:
      - build
    jobs:
      - job: D

  - stage: deploy_manual_approval
    displayName: 'Deployment Approval'
    dependsOn: tests
    condition: failed()
    jobs:
      - job: E

  - stage: deploy_dev
    displayName: 'Deploy: dev env'
    dependsOn:
      - build
      - tests
      - deploy_manual_approval 
    condition: |
      or(
        and(
          in(dependencies.tests.result, 'Succeeded', 'Skipped'),
          succeeded('build')
        ),
        and(
          succeeded(dependencies.deploy_manual_approval.result),
          succeeded('build')
        )
      )
    jobs:
      - F

From what I understand, since I explicitly say when tests is skipped OR succeeded and build is successful, the deploy stage should run and not be skipped. But this is not the case.
Can anyone point out where my conditional logic is wrong? Or maybe something I misunderstand with Azure pipelines as a whole. Thanks!

I can reproduce the same issue when manually skipping the dependencies stages with the same condition as yours.
I called the API "Timeline - Get" to get the detailed of the problematic runs and found that:

If the dependencies stages are skipped by manual, the value of "dependencies.<stage-name>.result" is always evaluated as "Null" in the "in(xxx)" expression. So, the expression "in(xxx)" always returns "False".


If the dependencies stages are skipped by the condition set on each of the dependencies stages, the same condition can work as expected.

In addition, the condition you set on stage "deploy_dev" can be reduced like as below.
stages:
. . .

- stage: deploy_dev
  displayName: 'Deploy: dev env'
  dependsOn:
    - build
    - tests
    - deploy_manual_approval 
  condition: |
    and(
      succeeded('build'),
      or(
        in(dependencies.tests.result, 'Succeeded', 'Skipped'),
        succeeded('deploy_manual_approval')
      )
    )
  jobs:
  . . .




For your case, as workaround, you can use parameters to select whether skipping any of the stages "scans", "tests" and "deploy_manual_approval", and set condition on each of these three stages to check the value of the parameters. See below YAML sample as reference.
parameters:
- name: skipStages
  displayName: 'Enter the stages you want to skip:'
  type: object
  default:
    - scans
    - tests
    - deploy_manual_approval

stages:
- stage: prebuild
  displayName: 'Pre-pipeline'
  jobs:
  . . .

- stage: build
  displayName: 'Build'
  dependsOn: prebuild
  jobs:
  . . .

- stage: scans
  displayName: 'Scans'
  dependsOn: build
  condition: and(succeeded(), not(${{ containsValue(parameters.skipStages, 'scans') }}))
  jobs:
  . . .

- stage: tests
  displayName: 'Tests'
  dependsOn: build
  condition: and(succeeded(), not(${{ containsValue(parameters.skipStages, 'tests') }}))
  jobs:
  . . .

- stage: deploy_manual_approval
  displayName: 'Deployment Approval'
  dependsOn: tests
  condition: and(failed(), not(${{ containsValue(parameters.skipStages, 'tests') }}))
  jobs:
  . . .

- stage: deploy_dev
  displayName: 'Deploy: dev env'
  dependsOn:
    - build
    - tests
    - deploy_manual_approval 
  condition: |
    and(
      succeeded('build'),
      or(
        in(dependencies.tests.result, 'Succeeded', 'Skipped'),
        succeeded('deploy_manual_approval')
      )
    )
  jobs:
  . . .




Thanks for taking the time to repro it and for your suggestion! Do you think I could just add Null to the conditions in the in(...) to check if it's been skipped manually? Would you see any drawbacks to this?
I think your proposed solution will do the job, but just out of curiosity.

Actually, adding pipeline parameters manually to specify which stages to skip would mean adding this to dozens of repos (instead of in a centralized template) for me. Ideally I can leverage the existing "Stages to run" functionality of Azure Pipelines for this.

@AdrianPatterson, I cannot to say whether the returned 'Null' value is a designed behavior or a defect/bug when manually skipping the stages. If the 'Null' value only occurs when manually skipping the stages, sure, you can add it as an item in the 'in(xxxx)' expression.

Null did not work, either as a string or passed as is. So it is not a viable solution for my case.

@AdrianPatterson, If the Null value is not work in the  'in(xxxx)' expression, you may need to use the workaround shared in my above answer.

Thanks for the debugging tip of using the API, helped me a lot
